# Steering wheel shakes and wobbles bad at 70km+

Tags: ford, mustang

Hey everyone I got a 99 v6 mustang and I just bought it off buddy, not bad at all. Only problem is that the steering wheel starts to shake and just gets worse with more speed. It settles down around 110 but it feels like my wheels are going to fall off! He's got aftermarket 17 inch riddler rims, and the tires arn't that bad, I havnt balanced them yet but I can see he's got like stick on weights in the actual rim, just curious on what I should do! Ps have had an alignment done recently, regardless off shakyness.

Comment: It's more than likely an imbalance, The tape weights can come off pretty easily.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, Alignment & Wheel Balancing should take care of it, unless you have some structural components that are starting to fail or have failed.
The alignment shop would be able to tell (and not continue with the alignment job) if something is broken.